# Не работает :nth-child

Tags: css

Разъясните пожалуйста почему не работает `:nth-child`.

```css
.container {
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: center
}

.container div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container:nth-child(7) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы же выбрали родителя, а надо дочерние выбирать. `.container:nth-child(7)` будет искать седьмой контейнер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы указали для контейнера а надо для дива в контейнере

```css
.container {
    width:450px;
    height:250px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center
}
.container div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px; 
    background: green;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.container div:nth-child(7) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Вот что бы получилось если было бы 7 контейнеров и css как у вас

```css
.container {
    width:450px;
    height:250px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center
}
.container div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px; 
    background: green;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.container:nth-child(7) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо задать так `.container div:nth-child(7)`

```css
.container {
    width:450px;
    height:250px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center
}
.container div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px; 
    background: green;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.container div:nth-child(7) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```